# How can I deal with this error in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When I run this code:

```r
ui1 <- fluidPage(
  textInput("usubjid","Search usubjid",""),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server1 <- function(input,output)
  {
    
    adae0<-reactive({
      if(length(input$usubjid)==0)
      {
        adae
      }
      else
      {
        subset(adae,USUBJID==input$usubjid)
      }
    })    
  
    output$table <- renderTable
    (
      {
        adae0() %>%
          select(USUBJID,AEREFID,AGE,SEX,AEBODSYS)
      }
    )
  }

shinyApp(ui=ui1,server=server1)
```

The error comes:

[image]

I want to know why and how i can fix it. Thanks. I am new to R shiny, and ask for help. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `adae` in your code?

Comment: adae is a dataset

Comment: Okay, i see it. I believe you need to first import/load this `adae` dataset, otherwise how can the program understand what is `adae`. BTW, i would always load the packages and dataset right at the beginning (before ui) rather than within server.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dplyr` without loading the library:
After loading `dplyr` package the code should run.
See in server part: `library(dplyr)`

```
ui1 <- fluidPage(
  textInput("usubjid","Search usubjid",""),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server1 <- function(input,output)
library(dplyr)
  {
  
  adae0<-reactive({
    if(length(input$usubjid)==0)
    {
      adae
    }
    else
    {
      subset(adae,USUBJID==input$usubjid)
    }
  })    
  
  output$table <- renderTable
  (
    {
      adae0() %>%
        select(USUBJID,AEREFID,AGE,SEX,AEBODSYS)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui=ui1,server=server1)
```